# how to see the command file in slurm

Tags: slurm

If I submitted a job using slurm, how can a see the full command file that was submitted, usually a bash script that start with :
#SBATCH --job-name=

how can I use slurm command to see the content of this script file (I know I can do scontorol show jobId -xxx and see where the script is, but assuming it was deleted or changed, and I still want to see the original script that was submitted to slurm)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On older versions of Slurm (17.02 and before), you can do `scontrol show -dd job <jobid>` to have Slurm display the content of the submission script it stored, and in newer versions of Slurm (17.11 and after), you would use `scontrol write batch_script <jobid> -`.

Comment: Thanks, Is it also possible to see the script of a job that was already completed?

Comment: I am afraid it id not possible